# When to distinguish OS versions in canonical names for target platforms

Tags: operating-systems, release-management, computer-architecture

I would like to organize my company's software releases by platform. I've looked at how [Mozilla](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/11.0/), [Perforce](ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/), and [Apache](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/) organize their releases, and it seems that I should partition by OS and processor architecture. I was thinking of something like this:

- Linux (x86-32)
- Linux (x86-64)
- Neutrino (x86-32)
- Windows (x86-32)
- Windows (x86-64)

Is it common to distinguish between versions of Windows, Linux, or OS X? For example, should I be specifying the Linux kernel version?

Comment: You have Neutrino and not OSX? How odd...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say only if it matters. If you *know* there are issues with the prior version(s) of the kernel OR if you have not tested with earlier versions, then you should put something like "3.3+" to indicate that anything *after* kernel 3.3 is known to be tested and good. Anything else is unsupported - it may work, it may not.